# Money Transfer with wrong IBAN

Tags: germany, transfer, swift, iban, egypt

i made a send payment from 5 days ago and now I was surprised that i forgot one number from IBAN and IBAN is incorrect,does that mean money still in my country? i know that the Bank will receive payment request but when he will see IBAN will see that one number missing (first number after Germany code)
so if the money is not still here in my country so when i will get them back?
Thanks.

Comment: I know that will happen. The receiving bank will receive the payment message
        They notice that they don't manage that account number (the bank part of the IBAN will not match them or any of their subsidiaries).
        They will reply to your bank that they are unable to process the payment
        Your bank will put the money back into your account.

In   But what gonna happen in my case?!

Comment: I am quite sure that the sending bank SHOULD have checked the validity of the account number. Even if they don't check the length, they at least should check the checksum. In the case where the check fails, they shouldn't process the transfer at the first place.